# FPM: How to get the list of files present in the rpm in the after-install shell script

Tags: rpm

I have a requirement to automate the deployment process onto the weblogic server by packaging the artifacts into an rpm and calling the after-install script which in turn calls the wlst script. Totally, there are 5 artifacts in the rpm, 4 shared libraries and 1 EAR. Depending on the artifact name/extension, i will be deploying the artifact as a shared library/application.

The question is how to get the list of files present in the rpm in the after-install shell script?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to generate a manifest when building and add the manifest to the package in %files. Read the just installed manifest
in your %post script.

Answer (score 0):

Will **rpm -ql** help? Example:

```
[root@alexander ~]# rpm -ql dhcp-libs-4.2.5-27.el7.centos.2.x86_64
/usr/lib64/libdhcpctl.so.0
/usr/lib64/libdhcpctl.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/libomapi.so.0
/usr/lib64/libomapi.so.0.0.0
```